# PSTN Call is not working over opensip instalaltion

Tags: sip, voip, opensips

we have already installed opensip  over asterisk but i want to move PSTN calls over asterisk .
Opensip working veru fine in extension to extension call . But i want The Public Switched Telephone Network (PSTN) over asterisk server.

Comment: I suggest you read this answer first, it looks like what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57141822/2054305